# Azure App Service Bicep Network Access Restrictions Disallow public access

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-appservice, azure-bicep

I have a set of Azure App Services deployed via bicep. These will use Private endpoints as a backend service.

I've checked Resource Explorer, dumped an existing App to ARM and converted it to Bicep, and searched all of the documentation, but I'm unable to find anything about "Allow public access", and how to set it to false.

How can I set "Allow public access" to false under the Networking section?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#siteproperties), you are looking for this property (available since api version 2020-12-01):

> publicNetworkAccess: Property to allow or block all public traffic. Allowed Values: 'Enabled', 'Disabled' or an empty string.

Just created a new app service plan with webappand it is working. Not sureabout existing webapp ...

```bicep
param appServicePlanName string = 'thomastest-nopublicaccess-asp'
param webAppName string = 'thomastest-nopublicaccess-wba'

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2018-11-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  sku: {
    tier: 'PremiumV2'
    name: 'P1V2'
  }
  properties: {
    name: appServicePlanName
    workerSize: 6
    workerSizeId: 6
    numberOfWorkers: 1
    zoneRedundant: false
  }
}

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: webAppName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    name: webAppName
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    httpsOnly: true
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: []
      metadata: [
        {
          name: 'CURRENT_STACK'
          value: 'dotnet'
        }
      ]
      phpVersion: 'OFF'
      netFrameworkVersion: 'v6.0'
      alwaysOn: true
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried 3 deployments, only setting publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'  in Properties or siteConfig, and a final deployment in both Properties and siteConfig, and Allow Public Access is still enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, will have a look as well

Comment: I've tried with a function app. what type of app service are you deploying ? which sku ? And also could you let me know the api-version you are using

Comment: Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01
Web App on Premium V2

Comment: so i tried with premiuim v2 and it worked on my side, would you be able to create a new app service plan and check that out please ?

Comment: I was including an older module file that was missing the publicNetworkAccess value. With that cleared up, I was able to clear the setting, thanks!